# Is this an Admin rights issue? the following copy command now returns Path / File access error

Tags: vba, command, admin, restriction

The following copy command now returns `runtime error 75 Path / File access error` There are no restrictions to access to the network drives and the process can be done manually but not when it's part of a macro?

```
FileCopy "V:\T&SH\SH&P\AM&P\HA&D\Highways Schemes\DATA\Preconstruction_Doc", "V:\T&SH\SH&P\AM&P\HA&D\Highways Schemes\4265 U5430 Cocker Lane\9. Health & Safety\3. Pre Construction Info"
```

The path names are all correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure since I don't have a lot of experience in computers themselves. Just a student in new media and communications.

But isn't it possible that the files or directories are 'open' at the moment and by that manner that you couldn't acces it?

This is just a guess but maybe it's right :)

(And are you logged in in as admin? Maybe that's a cause too)

My sincerely

Comment: Are you trying to copy a single file or a whole directory full of files?  If a single file, is it really the case that the file has no extension, or does it have an extension that Windows is hiding from you (the designed-by-an-imbecile default)

Comment: I guess it kinda looks like a folder? But not sure.. We'll have to wait for an answer

Comment: And while we wait:  FileCopy won't copy a folder full of files; it works only on a file at a time.  And if the file has an extension, it much be included in the command, whether Windows is DISPLAYING the extension or not.

Comment: You've pretty much narrowed the problem down, nice!
And I think there's also a FolderCopy command

Comment: I don't know of a FolderCopy command in VB/VBA; usually it's a matter of putting the FileCopy command inside a loop that FileCopy's each file that Dir$() returns.  The FileSystem object has a CopyFolder method though:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264819.aspx

Comment: Suppose that you would solve it programatically, how will you handle then subdirectories and so on? And that the files are placed in the right folder?
This is just a question out of my own interest, I'm studying IT and I really like programming and I want to learn as much as possible. Think I'm gonna try it one day.

And that method you gave, states that it applies to VBA. Can't you use it then? if you use a filesystem object set to that folder?

Comment: A google search should turn up plenty of examples of handling file copying including subdirectories and the files within them.  You can certainly use the FileSystem object in VBA, as per the example.  But both of these topics are outside the scope of the original question.